# Postdoc or permanent position

Tags: phd, research-process, application, postdocs, career-path

I am finishing my PhD soon and am working on computational chemistry within biomolecules.

On the one hand, I would love to go for a postdoc: to learn something and also earn a bigger penny. On the other, the University offered a position as a research assistant professor. Following the consulations it is similar to the anglosaxon Assistant Professor (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assistant_professor) or German Juniorprofessor (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junior_professorship), though here the contract period is not restricted and I do entirely scientific stuff, without didactics.

As I poked around on the web, I found that postdoc should be considered temporary employment, and it is especially important for young PhDs, for whom it is just hard to find a permanent position, but also to get them started in things like project writing, research design; briefly to gather experience.

I am quite active academically as I can self-publish in good journals, have foreign collaborations, as well as planned exchanges in other academic centers. Moreover, I expect to be habilitated within 2-3 years given how my "career" is developing.

Thus the question arose: is then postdoc something for me?... Could I go for it after habilitation or before it while still being employed at my University? I am particularly interested in the `scientific' dimension, that is, how the lack of a postdoc is actually perceived in the scientific world if I decide to move to western country for the position? Will lack of the postdoc in my resume be considered as a disadvantage?

Regards!

Comment: You should read your employment contract and the relevant laws.  Consider salary, location, and your personal goals.  As it is, this question seems wrong since Wikipedia is quite specific that a junior professor is limited to six years.  Is this Germany?

Comment: https://www.science.org/content/article/junior-professors-rise

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist No, I'm not German. Just used this for the readers might find it easier to understand (presumably, because of wikipedia entry) than the name it has in my country. I have changed the question slightly to make it more understandable now.

Comment: It's very vague after the edits.

Comment: Read the contract.  Nobody cares if you have had the postdoc job title.

Answer (score 1):

As you have learned, I think, most people take a post doc for one of two reasons. Either they can't find a suitable permanent position at the moment, or they think the post doc will enhance their CV to enable a better permanent position than they can get now.

But, while the terminology is different, it seems like you are being offered a permanent position doing what you love. If that is the case, I'd guess that a post doc would be both a waste of time and risky as there are no guarantees that the post doc leads to a better position, given changes in the economy and other uncontrollable things.

*If a research assistant professorship at a university like yours is your actual goal, then I'd suggest grabbing it.*

The sorts of things you would learn as a post doc can also be learned as an assistant prof. Moreover, you have more control over your career (most cases) as one usually works a post doc under the supervision of a PI. Not so much as an assistant professor. But, yes, terminology can differ.

It would be hard to imagine better pay in a post doc than in a permanent position, actually, and certainly better job security.

Comment: "hard to imagine": I was better off financially as a postdoc than as faculty, because the costs of relocating to take up the faculty job involved taking on additional debt, and the cost of servicing that debt absorbed the salary increase and a bit more besides.  (And it didn't help that my transition from postdoc to faculty happened just as academic salaries in England and Wales stopped being uprated with inflation.)

Comment: @DanielHatton - the university didn’t relocate you? Wow.

Comment: @JonCuster They had an unusually generous relocation expenses scheme as employers go, but it still only covered about half of the actual costs.

Comment: A recent (experienced) hire in my group had to pay some costs. Everything in his house was covered, but the tractor, boat, and other stuff in his barn he chose to drive out himself.